# How to play openload videos in lower quality with VLC?

Tags: vlc-media-player

I only have slow internet enough to play 480p quality youtube videos without buffering.

I was able to play a 1080p youtube videos to 240p with VLC using this step:

Step 1: Run VLC media player and navigate to Tools > Preferences.

Step 2: Under Show settings, select All.

Step 3: Click on inputs / codec tab on the left. Under Track Settings, click the Preferred video resolution drop-down list (I chose very low definition [240 lines])

....but this doesn't work with openload videos.

Most of openload videos I'm watching are in 720p to 1080p quality, and I tried to stream them with the same method as youtube (as I stated above) but the quality stays 720p, keeps buffering.